# O Google indexa imagens em SVG (inline) ou Base64?

Tags: html, css, google, seo, svg

Estava pensando em transformar o logotipo de um site para SVG, mas estava pensando em usá-lo de forma *inline* direto como código dentro das tags `<svg>`. Por ser *inline*, posso interagir como o SVG direto pelo CSS, com a `imagem.svg` não consigo fazer o que quero.

Aí ficou a dúvida. Sendo a imagem um SVG *inline*, direto no corpo do documento, ela seria indexada pelo Google? Sei que imagens Base64 não ficam em *cache*, mas será que esses códigos são considerados pelos motores de busca como uma imagem? Como fica a questão do SEO e do *alt text* nessa situação?

Quando a pessoa pesquisar no Google "Logo da Empresa X", se esse logo for um SVG *inline* o Google não vai retornar nada?

**Ex. de uma página com o logo em SVG *inline*:**
 *(deixei uns comentários no código)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    

    <div id="logo">

        <!-- O Google vai indexar essa tag SVG abaixo como uma imagem nos resultados de busca?? -->
        
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
            <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
            <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
        </svg>
    </div>

<!-- Imagens com extencao .svg eu sei que o Google indexa, mas e no caso acima como fica? O Google renderia a tag <svg> e entrega uma imagem no resultado de busca? -->

<img src="imagem.svg">


</body>
</html>
```

Segundo esse link parece que o Google indexa `imagens.svg`, mas sobre imagens construídas dentro das tags `<svg></svg>` eles não falam nada... https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html

**OBS:** Se possível gostaria de uma resposta com *fontes*, ou com algum *teste* de indexação feito no Google, ou até com algum estudo de caso... Mas repostas baseadas no "*achismo*" não tenho interesse.

Comment: Creio  que o  google não vai indexar um arquivo base64 urlencoded,  pois ele usa sua url da imagem como  base para fazer o index no  seu  sistema de  busca.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56701/image-data-uri-and-seo veja esse link

Comment: nele fala que o  google não vai  indexar data-URI

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-SVG-images-good-for-SEO

Comment: Esta referência indica que você use <title> e <desc> dentro da tag <svg> para funcionamento homônimo. https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/

Comment: @AndreMesquita obrigado pelos link

Comment: @MarcosBrinner valeu a dica!

Comment: De fato o Google indexa o `<text>` do SVG, sendo inline ou não. Mas o que você pode tentar é utilizar o schema.org para logos. Assim você consegue indexar, o Google vai entender como uma logo e ainda vai utilizar para SEO semântico. https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/05/using-schemaorg-markup-for-organization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nós indexamos o conteúdo SVG **independentemente de ele estar em um arquivo separado ou incorporado diretamente em HTML**. A Web é grande, portanto, pode levar algum tempo até rastrear e indexar a maioria dos arquivos SVG, mas a partir de hoje você pode começar a vê-los em sua pesquisa se realmente precisar tente pesquisar por [sitemap site: fastsvg.com] ou [site HideShow: svg-whiz.com]"

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html 
- Contra Google não há argumentos.

Comment: Não é uma imagem.svg que tenho dúvida, essa eu sei que ele indexa. Eu quero saber é se eu colocar o código do SVG direto dentro do HTML com a tag `<svg>` se esse código é indexado ou não pelo Google em forma de imagem.

Comment: Bem ao fazer uma pesquisa no Google images utilizando o `filetype:SVG` ele retorna imagens e ao visitar a página você pode ver que as imagens estão em código

Comment: Jovem aquo que vc ainda não entendeu... Só de pesquisar por "filetype:svg" vc já está dizendo que está procurando um tipo de arquivo de tem a extensão `.svg` não é essa minha dúvida. Eu sei que ele indexa imagem `.svg` eu quero saber se ele "transforma" uma tag `<svg>` que está no documento em uma imagem.svg e mostra no resultado de pesquisa.... pois até onde vi não sei se ele faz essa "conversão"  Tipo esse SVG `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 

</svg>` direto no HTML, como ele retorna isso na pesquisa? Ou não retorna nada?

Comment: Cara eu não tenho certeza da pergunta que você fez, mas espero que esse link possa te ajudar http://graph.fedwiki.org/view/graph-plugin

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei um exemplo para ficar mais fácil para visualizarem o minha dúvida.

Comment: "We index SVG content whether it is **in a standalone file** or **embedded directly in HTML**. The web is big, so it may take some time before we crawl and index most SVG files, but as of today you may start seeing them in your search results. If you want to see it yourself, try searching for [sitemap site:fastsvg.com] or [HideShow site:svg-whiz.com]"

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html

Contra a google não há argumentos

Comment: Faça uma tradção disso e coloque na edição da sua resposta, vai ficar melhor

Comment: Considere feito

Answer (score 0):

A maior parte indexada que o Google reconhece em suas pesquisas "rotineiras"  está em Base64.

Você pode testar pesquisando:

```
monte libano tab-educativos.svg
```

Em seguida clique no link abaixo da sugestão que vai ser gerado:

Algo como => "Imagens de monte libano tab-educativos.svg"

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=monte+libano+tab-educativos.svg&rlz=1C1JZAP_pt-BRBR814BR814&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiizeS42OrdAhUJPJAKHS_FA9IQsAR6BAgGEAE&biw=1920&bih=969

Clique na imagem ("Porta tudo") de exemplo:

Link da Imagem Indexada em Base64 abaixo:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Link da Imagem no Site:

http://www.montelibano.com.br/assets/Imagens/icones/navegacao/tab-porta-tudo.svg